# vuejs project unable to compile

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, compiler-errors, package.json

I've been tasked with fixing an older project. I'm using node 16.13.0 and npm 9.6.2 and vue/cli 5.0.8

It's using vue 2.0 and whenever I try to compile the project, I'm getting these error messages.

ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

options should NOT have additional properties
options should NOT have additional properties
options should NOT have additional properties
options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
options should match exactly one schema in oneOf

I've been doing some research and realize this could be a problem with webpack versions?

Here is my package.json:

```
  "name": "realtor",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.13",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.9",
    "vuetify": "^2.3.3",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "fibers": "^4.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.29.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Here is my webpack list.

```
├─┬ @vue/cli-plugin-babel@5.0.8
│ ├─┬ babel-loader@8.2.2
│ │ └── webpack@4.44.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ thread-loader@3.0.4
│ │ └── webpack@4.44.2 deduped
│ └─┬ webpack@5.88.2
│   └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.9
│     └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
├─┬ @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@5.0.8
│ ├─┬ eslint-webpack-plugin@3.2.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ └─┬ webpack@5.88.2
│   └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.9
│     └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
├─┬ @vue/cli-service@5.0.8
│ ├─┬ @soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@1.8.1
│ │ └── webpack@4.44.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ @vue/vue-loader-v15@npm:vue-loader@15.10.1
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ copy-webpack-plugin@9.1.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ css-loader@6.8.1
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ css-minimizer-webpack-plugin@3.4.1
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ html-webpack-plugin@5.5.3
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ mini-css-extract-plugin@2.7.6
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ postcss-loader@6.2.1
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ progress-webpack-plugin@1.0.16
│ │ └── webpack@4.44.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.9
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ vue-loader@17.2.2
│ │ └── webpack@4.44.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ webpack-dev-server@4.15.1
│ │ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@5.3.3
│ │ │ └── webpack@4.44.2 deduped
│ │ └── webpack@4.44.2 deduped
│ └── webpack@5.88.2
├─┬ sass-loader@8.0.2
│ └─┬ webpack@4.44.2
│   └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5
│     └── webpack@4.44.2 deduped
├─┬ vue-cli-plugin-vuetify@2.0.7
│ └─┬ null-loader@3.0.0
│   └── webpack@4.44.2 deduped
└─┬ vuetify-loader@1.6.0
  ├─┬ file-loader@4.3.0
  │ └── webpack@4.44.2 deduped
  └── webpack@4.44.2 deduped
```

Notice how some dependencies are using different webpack versions? These should all be the same, correct? (either all 4.44.2 or 5.88.2)

I took a look at another project I've been working on and noticed that some of my dev dependency versions are different that this project I've been assigned to. Same version of node, npm, and vue/cli as the new project I've been assigned to.

```
  "name": "bolt",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dongido/vue-viaudio": "^0.3.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "jspdf": "^2.1.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.13",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-core-video-player": "^0.1.9",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.3.3",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.0",
    "xlsx-style": "^0.8.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

And here's the webpack list.

```
├─┬ @vue/cli-plugin-babel@4.4.6
│ ├─┬ babel-loader@8.1.0
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ cache-loader@4.1.0
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ thread-loader@2.1.3
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ └─┬ webpack@4.43.0
│   └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.4
│     └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
├─┬ @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.4.6
│ ├─┬ eslint-loader@2.2.1
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
├─┬ @vue/cli-service@4.4.6
│ ├─┬ @intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin@1.0.6
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@1.7.1
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @vue/preload-webpack-plugin@1.1.1
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ copy-webpack-plugin@5.1.2
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ css-loader@3.6.0
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ file-loader@4.3.0
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ mini-css-extract-plugin@0.9.0
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@2.3.7
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ url-loader@2.3.0
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ vue-loader@15.9.3
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ webpack-dev-server@3.11.3
│ │ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2
│ │ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ │ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
│ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
├─┬ sass-loader@8.0.2
│ └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
└─┬ vuetify-loader@1.5.0
  └── webpack@4.43.0 deduped
```

This project does compile. I can do a npm run serve and npm run build with no issues.

My first thought is to downgrade these dependencies.

```
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
```

I've run this command.

```
npm install @vue/cli-plugin-babel@4.4.6 @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.4.6 @vue/cli-plugin-router 4.4.6 @vue/cli-plugin-vuex@4.4.6 @vue/cli-service@4.4.6
```

and am finding out that versions 4.4.6 are not available anymore. I'm at a loss on what to do. Can anyone provide some suggestions?